# How to keep a reactive UI while doing heavy computation with WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, emscripten

I use a C++ library doing heavy image processing at loading, compiled with emscripten and embedded in an angular application.
This code freezes the UI for a few seconds, which is never nice for the user.

I guess the two options here are

- to split the heavy computation into several asynchronous calls
- to use [threads (WebWorkers)](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/pthreads.html)

Although I'm not sure how feasible each one is, depending on the computation code.

What are the advantages/inconvenients of each? What's the usual way to deal with heavy computation with JS/WASM?

Answer (score 1):

I've done both.

Just **asynchronous** would still be on the main thread so it doesn't have any benefit in your situation. However, if you can split the processing into smaller chunks and feed them over time to a [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback), it can be pretty effective. The downside of that is that you have no real control of when (if ever) it will finish. Depending on how critical the output is it might not be the best for you. The upside is that you do have access to all of the APIs and not just the ones available to web workers. Here's an [example of implementation](https://gist.github.com/Sheraff/6b549ebf3d79f60b2a2cffe1f3d7bf5a) of "splitting into smaller chunks and feeding it to a requestIdleCallback", and [here's how you use it](https://github.com/Sheraff/whiteboard-comics/blob/v2/modules/Alphabet.js#:%7E:text=new%20IdlePromise).

Using a **web worker thread** has the big upside of completely freeing up the main thread, which will allow you to get the result faster. The downsides are that you only have access to the web worker APIs, you have to find a way to communicate your output back to the main thread (if necessary), and it will still eat up a lot of CPU (meaning that while the main thread is technically "free" it might still be slowed down). If you can split your task into smaller chunks, you could even spawn more than one thread and get a smoother / faster user experience.

### main thread

- might freeze the page (or alternatively take a long time / never finish)
- gives you access to all of the APIs
- easier to start with, a little more complicated one you get into idle-until-urgent designs
- passing data to / from won't be a bottleneck

### web worker

- frees up the main thread (but might still slow down the client as a whole)
- not all APIs are available
- pretty straightforward once you get a handle on communicating w/ the main thread
- gets complicated if you try to spawn more workers to work in parallel
- if your output isn't straightforward to structure as a SharedArray, passing big amounts of data might be an issue / a bottleneck

Comment: Thanks! However you are answering about JS I assume? WebAssembly might have some limitations on this? Like using `requestIdleCallback` from the C++

Comment: @ymoreau I only know Rust for WebAssembly but I know you can at least call a wasm function from a JS callback, so you can bind your chunks of processing w/ a requestIdleCallback.

Comment: Here's an example where I'm doing something similar but for `requestAnimationFrame`: https://github.com/Sheraff/boids/blob/master/js/rustWorker.js#:~:text=requestAnimationFrame